# LINQ to SQL: lambda expression vs .Where()

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

Are

```
var movies = from m in db.Movies
             select m;

movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
```

and

```
var movies = from m in db.Movies
             where String.Equals(m.Title,searchString)
             select m;
```

equivalent?  And if so, why use one over the other?  The syntax of the former seems more cryptic than the latter.

Comment: It's not *quite* a duplicate. This question is more about what's included in the compiled query.

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scenes, there's some translations going on.

For LINQ to SQL (and LINQ to Entities), the select keyword effectively ends a query. So, the second example has the filter as part of the SQL query, while the first one executes after the query.

There's a third way to do a LINQ query, called fluent syntax:

```cs
var movies = db.Movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
```

If you look at the [signature of Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535040%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you'd find this:

```cs
IQueryable<T> Where(IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate);
```

The key thing is the type of `predicate`: it's an expression of a (lambda) function, rather than merely a (lambda) function. This lets .Net dynamically convert the `Expression` object to SQL. For the query syntax, this parsing ends at `select`.

Answer (score 0):

query expressions are compiled to method syntax by compiler when you compile the code,
whichever way you write code is a matter of preference, query expressions are preferred by developers from sql background.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the latter form is more readable but sometimes you need the expression methods, like when you want to get the `Count` of result, and of course you can mix these two.